# How to get font details of a pdf using smalot pdfparser?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-parsing

I am using smalot pdfparser for parsing pdfs. While parsing, I am trying to get font details like font family, font size etc. According to this [API Doc](http://doc.pdfparser.org/namespaces/Smalot.PdfParser.html), it has mentioned getFonts and getFont methods. I am trying to get it, but getting some object. Follow this [link](http://pastebin.com/qfdwZDNm) to more about it. This is code I am using

```
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('hw.pdf');
$pages  = $pdf->getPages();
$page   = $pages[0];
$fonts = $page->getFonts();
print_r($fonts);
```

Kindly let me, if you have any idea. OR is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, just maybe, you don't need it anymore 2 year later :), but you can iterate over that collection and call `getName()`

```
foreach($page->getFonts() as $font) {
    print_r($font->getName() . PHP_EOL);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. This question is not relevant to me now, but still thanks. I'll check this soon as possible. And if it works, will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Spent a few hours struggling to figure out more font information, this method returned 'SNBIUK+HelveticaNeue-Bold' which for me is plenty of information :) Appreciated!